# Need a recommendation for a calculus book with a particular content structure

Tags: calculus

So, here's my problem. I'm not sure if it's something that can be helped given the specific nature, but here goes.

I'm supposed to be studying calculus for a university course.
The problem is, the provided textbooks are sickeningly stale and I feel like the material just isn't getting through, nor am I enjoying myself. I've been slamming my head against it ever since mid-march and I can't even get past the first chapter. I usually don't struggle this hard.

This isn't the first time this is happening, but I can usually solve this issue by finding alternative resources.
The issue is, the content structure/order in this course is infuriatingly unlike anything I've seen in other books.

For example, it starts with a lengthy chapter about real number properties, something none of the books I've found online seem to do. The next few chapters are about sequences, whereas every other calculus book I've found seems to touch on sequences and infinite series much later.

While I would love to study from something like Spivak or Larson's books, the content structure of the course means that I won't cover the right subjects in time to hand in the assignments, and the course will be a wash (though at this point I'm considering doing it anyway, if only to enjoy studying this subject as I did with the other subjects I've studied with alternative resources)

If someone could recommend a book with something along the lines of this order of content, I would greatly appreciate it.
It goes in this order: real numbers, sequences and limits, converging series and sequences, function limits, continuous functions, exponential functions, derivatives and lastly the properties of differentiable functions

Comment: What book are you currently trying to learn from?

Comment: They're textbooks published by the university I'm going to, I can't even find them online if I try to google them

Comment: This sounds like a very natural order. A classic book that is possibly slightly more advanced (but very widely used) is Walter Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis". Ch 1-5 cover real numbers/metric spaces, sequences and series, continuity, then differentiation. Choosing to learn from this book has the advantage that there are full solutions online, in-depth reading guides, and loads of helpful hints from people online to help you along

Comment: It seems like a natural order to me too, I'm puzzled why the more frequently recommended books don't have this order, but there it is. Thanks for the recommendation, I'll look into it!

Comment: Apostol or Bartle and Sherbert

Comment: @Renard Judging by the table of contents, I'm pretty sure the Bartle and Sherbert one is perfect. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Try [The Calculus Story by Acheson](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34757446-the-calculus-story) for an unconventional take.